# Rails/Postgres enum implementation creating records with enum key, not its value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, enums, enumeration

Using Rails 6.1.1

I've created a postgres implementation of enums on rails. However, on record create, the enum column is saving the enums' key, not the value as I would expect.

Migration:

```
execute "CREATE TYPE member_status_type AS ENUM ('New Member', 'Member Status Not Set')"
add_column :members, :member_status, :member_status_type
```

MemberEnums.rb

```
MEMBER_STATUSES = {
new_member: "New Member",
member_status_not_set: "Member Status Not Set"}.freeze
```

Member Model:

```
enum member_status: MemberEnums::MEMBER_STATUSES
```

Member creation:

```
Member.create!({member_status: MemberEnums::MEMBERS_STATUSES[:new_member]})
```

Result:

```
=> #<Member id: 12, member_status: "new_member">
```

The result I'm expecting should be

```
=> #<Member id: 12, member_status: "New Member">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member Model:

```
enum status: MemberEnums::MEMBER_STATUSES
```

By changing the name of enum your desired results will be achieved. This might be happening because you have given the same name for the attribute and the enum